# jQuery Mobile: Binding if statement with tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

firstly here's the [fiddle](http://codepen.io/sarvagnya1/pen/mywbNV)

There are three div's, HTML code:

```
<div class="container" data-role="page" id="container">
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="close">
        </div><!-- /.close -->
    </div><!-- /.popup -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

.container - is a large background, it contains the page.
.popup - is a div inside the container.
.close - is a small white div inside the ".popup" div

This is what I want - when tapped anywhere on the page the entire div .container has to hide, except for popup, when tapped on popup, it should stay as it is.

Right now only one condition is satisfied, if tap happens anywhere the entire div .container disappears, now 
1. How do I prevent the div .container from disappearing when .popup div is tapped.

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#container",function(){
$(".container").on("tap",function(){    
  $(".container").hide();
  });                       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the tap event returned
jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#container",function(){
        $(".container").on("tap",function(tapEvent){
            if (!$(tapEvent.target).hasClass("popup")){
                $(".container").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
$('.popup').siblings().hide();
```

or

```
$('.container').children().not('.popup').hide();
```

It will hide the elements that have the same parent as `div.popup`.

Comment: it does not work my friend, thank you for replying though. may be could of if statements should work.